# An array of objects with each individual child of this object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i Have enteried JS object like this:

```
const arr = [
   {
       name: 'obj-1',
       children: [
           {
               name: 'obj-1-child1',
               children: [
                   {
                       name: 'obj-1-child1-child1',
                       children: [
                           {
                               name: 'obj-1-child1-child1-child1'
                           },
                           {
                               name: 'obj-1-child1-child1-child2'
                           }
                       ]
                   },
                   {
                       name: 'obj-1-child1-child2'
                   }
               ]
           },
           {
               name: 'obj-1-child1',
               children: [
                   {
                       name: 'obj-1-child2-child1',
                       children: [
                           {
                               name: 'obj-1-child2-child1-child1'
                           }
                       ]
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
   },
   {
       name: 'obj-2',
       children: [
           {
               name: 'obj-2-child1',
               children: [
                   {
                       name: 'obj-2-child1-child1'
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
]
```

I tried to do it by iterating the object with a FOR loop.
A separate object is needed for each step of this tree. obj1->child1 then obj1->child1->child1 then obj1->child1->child1->child1 etc for each step for all elements in tree

```
const arr1 = [
   {
       name: 'obj-1',
       children: [] // one object for 1 step in tree
   },
   {
       name: 'obj-1',
       children: [
           {
               name: 'obj-1-child1',
               children: []
           }
       ]
   },
   {
       name: 'obj-1',
       children: [
           {
               name: 'obj-1-child1',
               children: [
                   {
                       name: 'obj-1-child1-child1',
                       children: []
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
   },
   {
       name: 'obj-1',
       children: [
           {
               name: 'obj-1-child1',
               children: [
                   {
                       name: 'obj-1-child1-child1',
                       children: [
                           {
                               name: 'obj-1-child1-child1-child1'
                           }
                       ]
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
]
```

which means for such a tree, the result should be: 12 elements

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post. 

The question is, is it even possible to implement this and what is the best way to do this

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish but I think the technique you're looking for would be a recursive descent.  This will allow you to "visit" each object in the hierarchy without knowing, a priori, the shape of the tree (esp. the depth).  With this technique you could, e.g., flatten the tree by adding the name of each object to a list as you visit each node in the tree.